# Other ways to redirect page

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find a way to bypass a websites code that prevents page redirects. Is there any way to make a location.replace like this?

```
var te = "loca";
var st = "tion";

te + st.replace("url")
```

Comment: @zb' Are those quotes meant to be there around `te + st`?

Comment: sorry, no o'c they shouldn't